# How to stream Raspberry Pi camera feed to an Android VideoView

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

In a correctly working Fragment, I have put a VideoView in `video_feed_fragment_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

With the corresponding class code in `VideoFeedFragment` (imports omitted):

```
public class VideoFeedFragment extends Fragment {

    // Variable declaration
    private VideoView videoView;
    private Uri videoStream;


    // Mandatory empty constructor
    public VideoFeedFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_feed_fragment_layout, container, false);

        videoView = (VideoView) root.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoStream = Uri.parse("http://pi5.akoo.nl:9000");
        videoView.setVideoURI(videoStream);

        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });

        return root;
    }
}
```

On *http://pi5.akoo.nl:9000* VLC - running on a Raspberry Pi - is running and streams video output from a Raspberry Pi Camera Module that is connected on it.

The code above gives me the error "Can't play this video".
[image: Screenshot from the running app]

My question is how to solve this issue.

Comment: Should my browser show something when i use your link? Times out.

Comment: @greenapps That's correct, not currently streaming.

Comment: @greenapps You are absolutely right. However, I am working on this project within a project where I don't have access to the Raspberry Pi.